# ERROR: could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/redis_fdw.so": libhiredis.so.0.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

when I try to execute "create extension redis_fdw;",the terminal show **ERROR**:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/redis_fdw.so": libhiredis.so.0.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

At last , just copy libhiredis.so.0.11 to redis_fdw.so's folder.yeah, The problem is solved perfect